# Resizing a Page View in a Container

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a `ViewController` with a Container embedding a `PageViewController`. The container is using the Autolayout constraints and is resizing perfectly.

I want the `PageViewController` to resize and fill the Container. I have this code and its resizing the `PageViewController` to the value of the container (`containerForCharts` as an outlet in the `ViewController` code), but the values is before the Autosizing.

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = 
   CGRectMake(
       containerForCharts.frame.origin.x, 
       containerForCharts.frame.origin.y,
       containerForCharts.frame.width,
       containerForCharts.frame.height
   )
```

Is there a way I can resize the `PageViewController` to fill the container?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the resizing using

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   self.pageViewController.view.frame =
   CGRectMake(containerForCharts.frame.origin.x, 
   containerForCharts.frame.origin.y, 
   containerForCharts.frame.width,containerForCharts.frame.height )
}
```